# Rails: drawbacks of using Sass's @import instead of *=require

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, import, sass, turbolinks

I decided to use Sass's `@import` instead of Sprocket's `*=require`.

I have this in **application.scss**:

```
@import 'normalize';
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'variables';
```

and this in **blog.scss**:

```
@import 'application';
```

This way I have separate stylesheets for separate controllers (makes my code more organized).

To make this work, I also added `stylesheet_link_tag     params[:controller]` to my layout, then added `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( blog.css )` line to my */config/initializers/assets.rb* file and restarted the server.

Are there any drawback of this approach? Will *turbolinks* be slower?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rails Asset Pipeline guide actually recommends using Sass's @import instead of Sprockets *=require if you have multiple Sass files.

Here's a quote from the Rails Asset Pipeline guide:

"If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. When using Sprockets directives, Sass files exist within their own scope, making variables or mixins only available within the document they were defined in. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)"

This is also recommended on the sass-rails gem Github page (https://github.com/rails/sass-rails). Here's a quote from that page:

"Sprockets provides some directives that are placed inside of comments called require, require_tree, and require_self. DO NOT USE THEM IN YOUR SASS/SCSS FILES. They are very primitive and do not work well with Sass files. Instead, use Sass's native @import directive which sass-rails has customized to integrate with the conventions of your Rails projects."

There aren't any significant drawbacks to this approach and there are actually quite a few benefits (including, but not necessarily limited to):

1. The main advantages come from the fact that SASS @import creates a global namespace, while the Sprockets directives do not.
2. Compilation will speed up a bit in development, because it won’t have to re-compile  all the vendor mixins every time each partial @import’s it.
3. Using the @import global namespace creates a Whorfian effect where the developers on the team tend to define and reuse their variables where they should (in the variables files), and not in more specific files. For example, z-indexes can become a nightmare if not defined in a global variables file (https://content.pivotal.io/blog/structure-your-sass-files-with-import).

Comment: I've experienced very slow load times in development when i use only @imports particularly if using bootstrap-sass and a couple chooice compass components. I'm still trying to research the issue, but i'm not happy waiting 10 seconds to load the page in dev.

Comment: @LessQuesar:   What you are seeing is the compilation and execution of all imported files regardless of whether they've changed or not.  Sprockets doesn't have this setback.  Sprockets only recompiles the changed files, checkout the treehouse article listed below!

Answer (score 2):

The asset pipeline treats Sass @imports differently than it treats Sprockets. In the case of imports, each save will go through and compile all the imports each time, no matter which partial you’ve saved. The way that Sprockets are treated inside stylesheets is that only the partial you’ve saved will recompile and then be injected onto the page locally when you refresh.  This makes sprockets much faster than imports on average although using @import does have some benefits as listed elsewhere on this thread.  A good read on the subject can be found here by treehouse:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/tale-front-end-sanity-beware-sass-import

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering whether using multiple imports creates multiple HTTP requests, thereby creating overhead, this is what the sass website has to say about it:

> Sass builds on top of the current CSS @import but instead of requiring an HTTP request, Sass will take the file that you want to import and combine it with the file you're importing into so you can serve a single CSS file to the web browser.